# Could not read destination from environment variables locally with Version 4

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Currently all of our projects are working with Cloud SDK for Java version 3. I am evaluating Cloud SDK version 4 and check the possibilities to use it.

What I want to do is to connect to on-premise S/4HANA system and call standard odata service with type safe odata client. After the code is done, I tested it locally but failed. The error indicates it tried to get the binding destination service with an exception. Actually the destination is defined in environment variables in Intellij IDEA. It works fine with Cloud SDK version 3.

Below is my sample code.

```
public List<PurchaseOrder> getPurchaseOrders() throws Exception {
        
        HttpDestination destination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("T4X_HTTP_011")
                                                         .asHttp().decorate(DefaultErpHttpDestination::new);;

        List<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrders = new DefaultPurchaseOrderService()
                                            .getAllPurchaseOrder()
                                            .select(PurchaseOrder.PURCHASE_ORDER,
                                                    PurchaseOrder.PURCHASE_ORDER_TYPE,
                                                    PurchaseOrder.CREATION_DATE,
                                                    PurchaseOrder.CREATED_BY_USER,
                                                    PurchaseOrder.SUPPLIER)
                                            .filter(PurchaseOrder.PURCHASE_ORDER_TYPE.eq(PURCHASE_ORDER_TYPE))
                                            .orderBy(PurchaseOrder.PURCHASE_ORDER, Order.DESC)
                                            .top(10)
                                            .executeRequest(destination);

        logger.info("Get purchase order successfully.");
        return purchaseOrders;
    }
```

Destination
[image]

Error Stack Trace

```
2022-12-14 13:49:59.329  WARN 18296 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.c.s.c.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter  : Unexpected servlet filter exception: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get destination.

com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.exception.ThreadContextExecutionException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get destination.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.execute(ThreadContextExecutor.java:278)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter.doFilter(RequestAccessorFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get destination.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(RequestAccessorFilter.java:67)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ThreadContextExecutor.java:270)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.call(ThreadContextExecutor.java:302)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.execute(ThreadContextExecutor.java:269)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get destination.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.getDestinationConfigurationAsJson(ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.java:270)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.getDestinationConfigurationFromDestinationService(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:310)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.getDestinationConfigurationByTenant(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:248)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.getDestinationConfigurationByRetrievalStrategy(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:223)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.loadAndParseDestination(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:175)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.lambda$tryGetDestination$11b15c39$1(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:134)
    at io.vavr.control.Try.of(Try.java:75)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.tryGetDestination(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:134)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationLoaderChain.tryGetDestination(DestinationLoaderChain.java:82)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationLoader.tryGetDestination(DestinationLoader.java:37)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationAccessor.tryGetDestination(DestinationAccessor.java:142)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationAccessor.getDestination(DestinationAccessor.java:120)
    at com.bosch.sbs.purchaseorder.services.imp.MyPurchaseOrderServiceImp.getPurchaseOrders(MyPurchaseOrderServiceImp.java:27)
    at com.bosch.sbs.purchaseorder.controllers.MyPurchaseOrderController.getPurchaseOrders(MyPurchaseOrderController.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.resilience.ResilienceRuntimeException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.exception.ThreadContextExecutionException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.exception.TokenRequestFailedException: Failed to get destination service client identifier and secret. Please make sure to correctly bind your application to a destination service instance.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.lambda$null$3(Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.java:195)
    at io.vavr.control.Try.onFailure(Try.java:659)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.lambda$decorateCallable$4(Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.java:194)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.resilience.ResilienceDecorationStrategy.executeCallable(ResilienceDecorationStrategy.java:191)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.resilience.ResilienceDecorator.executeCallable(ResilienceDecorator.java:231)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.getDestinationConfigurationAsJson(ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.java:257)
    ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.exception.ThreadContextExecutionException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.exception.TokenRequestFailedException: Failed to get destination service client identifier and secret. Please make sure to correctly bind your application to a destination service instance.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.execute(ThreadContextExecutor.java:252)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.DefaultThreadContextExecutorService.lambda$decorate$0(DefaultThreadContextExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.exception.TokenRequestFailedException: Failed to get destination service client identifier and secret. Please make sure to correctly bind your application to a destination service instance.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ServiceCredentialsRetriever.getCredentials(ServiceCredentialsRetriever.java:43)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.getAccessTokenForDestinationService(ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.java:280)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.lambda$getDestinationConfigurationAsJson$0(ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.java:259)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.lambda$decorateCallable$2(Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.java:179)
    at io.github.resilience4j.bulkhead.Bulkhead.lambda$decorateCallable$4(Bulkhead.java:177)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.call(ThreadContextExecutor.java:302)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.execute(ThreadContextExecutor.java:246)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.exception.NoServiceBindingException: Failed to get 'destination' service credentials from VCAP_SERVICES variable: no service binding found for service plan '(any)'. Please make sure to correctly bind your application to a service instance of the destination service.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.ScpCfCloudPlatform.getServiceCredentials(ScpCfCloudPlatform.java:521)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.ScpCfCloudPlatform.getServiceCredentials(ScpCfCloudPlatform.java:447)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ServiceCredentialsRetriever.getCredentials(ServiceCredentialsRetriever.java:36)
    ... 11 common frames omitted

2022-12-14 13:49:59.334 ERROR 18296 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.exception.ShouldNotHappenException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.exception.ThreadContextExecutionException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get destination.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter.doFilter(RequestAccessorFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.exception.ThreadContextExecutionException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get destination.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.execute(ThreadContextExecutor.java:278)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter.doFilter(RequestAccessorFilter.java:67)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get destination.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(RequestAccessorFilter.java:67)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ThreadContextExecutor.java:270)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.call(ThreadContextExecutor.java:302)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.execute(ThreadContextExecutor.java:269)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException: Failed to get destination.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.getDestinationConfigurationAsJson(ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.java:270)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.getDestinationConfigurationFromDestinationService(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:310)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.getDestinationConfigurationByTenant(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:248)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.getDestinationConfigurationByRetrievalStrategy(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:223)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.loadAndParseDestination(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:175)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.lambda$tryGetDestination$11b15c39$1(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:134)
    at io.vavr.control.Try.of(Try.java:75)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.tryGetDestination(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:134)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationLoaderChain.tryGetDestination(DestinationLoaderChain.java:82)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationLoader.tryGetDestination(DestinationLoader.java:37)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationAccessor.tryGetDestination(DestinationAccessor.java:142)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.DestinationAccessor.getDestination(DestinationAccessor.java:120)
    at com.bosch.sbs.purchaseorder.services.imp.MyPurchaseOrderServiceImp.getPurchaseOrders(MyPurchaseOrderServiceImp.java:27)
    at com.bosch.sbs.purchaseorder.controllers.MyPurchaseOrderController.getPurchaseOrders(MyPurchaseOrderController.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.resilience.ResilienceRuntimeException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.exception.ThreadContextExecutionException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.exception.TokenRequestFailedException: Failed to get destination service client identifier and secret. Please make sure to correctly bind your application to a destination service instance.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.lambda$null$3(Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.java:195)
    at io.vavr.control.Try.onFailure(Try.java:659)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.lambda$decorateCallable$4(Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.java:194)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.resilience.ResilienceDecorationStrategy.executeCallable(ResilienceDecorationStrategy.java:191)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.resilience.ResilienceDecorator.executeCallable(ResilienceDecorator.java:231)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.getDestinationConfigurationAsJson(ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.java:257)
    ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.exception.ThreadContextExecutionException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.exception.TokenRequestFailedException: Failed to get destination service client identifier and secret. Please make sure to correctly bind your application to a destination service instance.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.execute(ThreadContextExecutor.java:252)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.DefaultThreadContextExecutorService.lambda$decorate$0(DefaultThreadContextExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.exception.TokenRequestFailedException: Failed to get destination service client identifier and secret. Please make sure to correctly bind your application to a destination service instance.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ServiceCredentialsRetriever.getCredentials(ServiceCredentialsRetriever.java:43)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.getAccessTokenForDestinationService(ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.java:280)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.lambda$getDestinationConfigurationAsJson$0(ScpCfDestinationServiceAdapter.java:259)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.resilience4j.Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.lambda$decorateCallable$2(Resilience4jDecorationStrategy.java:179)
    at io.github.resilience4j.bulkhead.Bulkhead.lambda$decorateCallable$4(Bulkhead.java:177)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.call(ThreadContextExecutor.java:302)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextExecutor.execute(ThreadContextExecutor.java:246)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.exception.NoServiceBindingException: Failed to get 'destination' service credentials from VCAP_SERVICES variable: no service binding found for service plan '(any)'. Please make sure to correctly bind your application to a service instance of the destination service.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.ScpCfCloudPlatform.getServiceCredentials(ScpCfCloudPlatform.java:521)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.ScpCfCloudPlatform.getServiceCredentials(ScpCfCloudPlatform.java:447)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ServiceCredentialsRetriever.getCredentials(ServiceCredentialsRetriever.java:36)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
```

Cloud SDK version: 4.2.0

=================Update=====================

After I deployed the application to BTP Cloud Foundry environment and execute request, the destination "T4X_HTTP_011" could not be found. The destination exists both in subaccount and instance level.

```
"Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationNotFoundException: No destination for name 'T4X_HTTP_011' could be found in any of the registered loaders. When your app runs on SAP Cloud Platform, make sure you have one of the following modules in your dependency tree: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:scp-neo or com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:scp-cf, depending on your SCP landscape.","\t... 64 more"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the local case: The destination name is different between your environment variable `T4X_011_HTTP` and your source code `T4X_HTTP_011`. Also your environment variable should have quotes around the parameters such as `"name":` instead of `name:`. And I would suggest to make sure all parameters are here such as `type`. Here is the [documentation](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/connectivity/destination-service#configure-destinations-manually) to help you.

For the BTP Cloud Foundry case, the name might be wrong, could you also send a screenshot of your BTP Cloud Foundry destination if this is not the case?

Comment: Sorry for the stupid mistake. I have changed the destination parameters accordingly. Now it works fine both locally and on BTP.